# Scala list to tuple conversion

Tags: scala

```
    def toPairs[A](xs : Seq[A]) : Seq[Tuple2[A,A]] = {
      @tailrec
      def accumulator(as : Seq[A], accum: Seq[Tuple2[A,A]]) : Seq[Tuple2[A,A]] = as match {
        case Nil => accum
        case x :: tail => tail match {
          case Nil => accum
          case _ =>  accumulator(as.tail, accum :+ (x,tail.head))
        }
      }

      accumulator(xs, Seq.empty[Tuple2[A,A]])
    }
```

I use this code for the following use case: for a Seq[A] i.e. List(1,2,3) I want a Seq of Tuples of A i.e. List((1,2)(2,3)). Is this the most optimal, idiomatic way in Scala, what could be improved?

For the record: the order of the elements is important and is expected to be congruent with the example in the preceding paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the way you go back and forth between `as` and `x` a bit annoying.  You should be able to collapse the nested `match` into one `match` that covers three cases.

The `:+` operator, which appends an element to a sequence, should be avoided at all costs, because it involves traversing to the end of the sequence.  That makes your algorithm O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), when it should ideally be O(*n*).

Anyway, the solution can be much simpler than that.

```
def toPairs[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[(A,A)] = xs.zip(xs.tail)
```

Comment: Awesome, esp. the short syntax of Tuple typeargs: (A,A) vs Tuple2[A,A]!